# Group one DataSet with Nested Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Suppose I have some book data like this:

[image]

And I have a query like `SELECT * FROM BookData` which outputs it in the above format.

I would like to use nested repeater controls to output the data in an html `<table>` that will look something like this, with the data results grouped by Author:

[image]

So far I have my asp.net web form code looking like this:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterInner" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Book") %>' /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' /></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("PublishDate") %>' /></td> 
        <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Pages") %>' /></td>         
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

and my behind code this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          

            DataSet ds = GetData();
            RepeaterInner.DataSource = ds;
            RepeaterInner.DataBind();

        }

        private DataSet GetData() 
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetData"))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    con.Close();
                    return ds;                   
                }
            }
        }
```

For the final product I want it to look like this:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterOuter" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterInner" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Book") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("PublishDate") %>' /></td> 
            <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Pages") %>' /></td>         
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>    
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

But I am really confused on what to do to make the above happen. Can it be done with my one `DataSet` above generated from my one stored procedure? What do I need to do for each Repeater's `ItemDataBound` event handler if anything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure looks to only return one table of data. So the GetData method should probably return a `DataTable` not a `DataSet`

```
private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString))
    {
        c.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetData", c))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Servy's solution helped me understand `IGrouping` better. Building more on his idea:
Your `Page_Load` method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTbl = this.GetData();

    //Cast the Rows collection so we can use LINQ
    IEnumerable<dynamic> data = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()

        // Group the DataRows by the column ["Author"]
        .GroupBy<DataRow, String>(d => Convert.ToString(d["Author"]))

        // GroupBy returns an IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>
        // in this case we have a String (Authors Name) and 
        // DataRows with the book information. From these IGroupings
        // we want to return a dynamic class that has properties:
        //  - Author (string it is the .Key in the IGrouping) 
        //  - Books (Collection of another dynamic class that has Book properties)
        .Select<IGrouping<String, DataRow>, dynamic>(grp => {
            return new {
                Author = grp.Key,
                // grp right now is a collection of DataRows
                // make each row into a dynamic class that has
                // book properties so that Eval("PropName")
                // plays nice
                Books = grp.Select<DataRow, dynamic>(row => {
                    return new {
                        Book = Convert.ToString(row["Book"]),
                        PublishDate = Convert.ToString(row["PublishDate"]),
                        Pages = Convert.ToString(row["Pages"])
                    };
                })
            };
        });

    RepeaterOuter.DataSource = data;
    RepeaterOuter.DataBind();
}
```

Page Code:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterOuter" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' /></td>
            </tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterInner" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Books") %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                   <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Book") %>' /></td>
                   <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PublishDate") %>' /></td> 
                   <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pages") %>' /></td>
                </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>    
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy` to group the data by author, and then you can simply bind the inner repeater to the group of books:

```
RepeaterOuter.DataSource = data.GroupBy(book => book.Author, (Author, Books) => new
{
    Author,
    Books,   
});
```

Now that you've transformed your data into the proper format you only need to bind the collectino of books to the inner repeater in your markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterInner" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Books") %>'>
```

Comment: What is `data` in `data.GroupBy(book => book.Author, (Author, Books)`? It does not exist in the `Page_Load` event.

Comment: @MicroR It's the data you have, that you want to use to populate your repeaters.

Comment: The data I have is in a `DataSet` and there is no `DataSet.GroupBy`. So what object has the `.GroupBy`?

Comment: @MicroR You'll need to get the rows of the table, rather than acting on the entire set.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am just not getting it with your explanation. I was also looking at this solution but not working either: http://forums.asp.net/t/1447268.aspx?How+to+use+a+nested+Repeater+for+a+Single+DataSet+

Answer (score 0):

A more simplified lambda expression for cmd.prompt's solution:

```
    DataTable data = GetData();

    var groupedData = data.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(d => new
        {
            Author = d["Author"]
        })
        .Select(grp => new
        {
            grp.Key,
            Books = grp.Select(row => new
            {
                Book = row["ID"],
                PublishDate = row["Name"],
                Pages = row["Pages"]
            })
        });

    RepeaterOuter.DataSource = groupedData;
    RepeaterOuter.DataBind();
```