# Child repeater does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a nested repeater inside of another repeater like this:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterOuter" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterInner" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Book") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("PublishDate") %>' /></td> 
            <td><asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Pages") %>' /></td>         
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>    
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

However, when I try to access the child repeater, RepeaterInner, from my code behind file, it says that it does not exist in the current context. The parent repeater, RepeaterOuter, does however.

I am trying to set up a loop, to loop through my TextBox's in the child repeater but it won't let me access it:

```
//does not work
foreach (RepeaterItem item in RepeaterInner.Items)
            {
                txtBook= (TextBox)item.FindControl("Book");
                txtPublishDate = (TextBox)item.FindControl("PublishDate");
                txtPages = (TextBox)item.FindControl("Pages");

                // do something....

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to access these controls like this from your code behind in the first place.  You should simply be binding the data to the repeater as was shown to you [the last time you asked about this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26164215/1159478).

Comment: @Servy, Thanks for your help but I couldn't understand it but found a way to use nested repeaters... So are you saying there is no way to access the nested repeater?

Comment: No, I'm saying *you shouldn't have to* not that you can't.  Given that you already have all of the bindingings in its template set up you only need to add *one new attribute* to properly bind the data, rather than writing a screen full of code to populate the data without binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I very much doubt this inner repeater even exists before the outer one is data bound. So make sure you are accessing inner repeater at a right time.

At second, controls that are in templates are not visible like this on the page. To get the control in the template you need to use `FindControl`. Also note that `FindControl` works only with direct children, so your code should look something like this:

```
var innerRepeater = RepeaterOuter.Items[0].FindControl("RepeaterInner") as Repeater;
```

Comment: That works great! You are correct: my inner repeater does not exist before the outer one is data bound. Perhaps this is the wrong way to do things but it is working for me right now. Btw, how can I find out how many elements are in the `RepeaterOuter.Items[]` array?

Comment: @MicroR, this is not not an array but a collection. And it has `Count` property, so `RepeaterOuter.Items.Count`